# Geometric Algebra Grade Projection

Tags: clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

I was reading through the book *Geometric Algebra for Physicist*, and, although I find it pretty useful, there are steps that I find missing and haven't been able to find in any other GA books.

I was hopping someone could explain the steps to me:
The equation (3.126) states, $x$ is a vector and $A,B$ are bi-vectors:

$$ A ·(x\wedge(x·B))=\langle Ax(x·B) \rangle = \langle (A·x)xB \rangle=B·(x\wedge(x·A)) $$

In equation (4.154), $f_{1,2}$ are vectors and $A_r,B_r$ are $r$-blades:

$$ \alpha \langle A_r(B_r·f_1)\wedge f_2\rangle =\alpha \langle f_2·A_rB_rf_1\rangle$$

Could someone explain with detail the steps followed?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first decomposition, 
since $ x \cdot B $ is a vector, $ x \wedge ( x \cdot B ) $ must be a bivector (grade 2).  The product of the bivector $ A $ with another bivector is a multivector with grades that may include 0, 2, 4, and the dot product of those two is the grade-0 selection.  That is
$$\begin{aligned}   A \cdot \left( { x \wedge (x \cdot B) } \right)   &=   \left\langle{{ A \left( { x \wedge (x \cdot B) } \right) }}\right\rangle \\    &=   \left\langle{{ A \left( { x (x \cdot B) - x \cdot (x \cdot B) } \right) }}\right\rangle.\end{aligned}$$
Here we used $ x y = x \cdot y + x \wedge y $, which leaves us a with a scalar factor $ x \cdot (x\cdot B) $, that has no contribution to the grade-0 selection, which leaves us with
$$\begin{aligned}   A \cdot \left( { x \wedge (x \cdot B) } \right)   &=   \left\langle{{ A x (x \cdot B) }}\right\rangle \\    &=   \left\langle{{ (A \cdot x) (x \cdot B) }}\right\rangle \\    &=   \left\langle{{ (A \cdot x) (x B - x \wedge B) }}\right\rangle \\    &=   \left\langle{{ (A \cdot x) x B }}\right\rangle.\end{aligned}$$
Here we made use of the fact that $ A x = A \cdot x + A \wedge x $, a vector and trivector, of which only the vector component contributes to the scalar selection.  Then we are free to rewrite $ x \cdot B $ in terms of $ x B $ and a trivector that also has no contritution to the scalar selection.  The final result follows from the fact that reversion of a scalar leaves it unchanged, so 
$$\begin{aligned}   \left\langle{{ (A \cdot x) x B }}\right\rangle   &=   \left\langle{{ B x (x \cdot A) }}\right\rangle \\    &=   B \cdot \left( { x \wedge (x \cdot A) } \right),\end{aligned}$$
where we are able to use the very first step to write the scalar selection back in terms of dots and wedges.

The result of 4.154 probably requires similar logic.

Comment: That scalar factor is $x\cdot(x\cdot B)=(x\wedge x)\cdot B=0$.